# Actualizar dos tablas al mismo tiempo (Update)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hola tengo un problema al actualizar dos tablas al mismo tiempo

**Controlador:**

```
/*Si se ejecuta el update*/
if($this->miembro->editar_miembro($editar_miembro, $id_usuario)) {
    /*Redireccionamos al listado de usuarios e indicamos que se actualizó correctamente*/
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registro editado correctamente');
    redirect(base_url()."index.php/perfil");
}//./if
```

**Modelo:**

```
public function editar_miembro($datos, $id_usuario)
{
    /*Indicamos el usuario a editar*/
    $this->db->where('id_usuario', $id_usuario);

    /*Ejecutamos el update en la base de datos*/
    $this->db->update('usuario', $datos);

    return TRUE;

} // /editar_carrera
```

Únicamente le estoy pasando los datos del usuario, solamente me está actualizando los datos del usuario y no le mando los datos de la empresa porque no se como armar el `Query`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se dan cuenta usuario tiene como `fk` `id_empresa`.

Comment: hasta ahora estas mandando un array con la info del usuario y el id del mismo para hacer un update a la tbl_usuario, pero en que momento mandas la info de la tbl_empresa para hacer su update? y en tu modelo tienes que tener esto para validar que se hizo el update correctamente ` return ( $this->db->affected_rows() != 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;`

Answer (score 5):

Lo que podes hacer, siempre que estés **relacionando correctamente** las consultas, es **ejecutar una única consulta UPDATE**, relacionando los campos, que **efectuará cambios** en dos tablas **simultaneamente**.

Esto significa que no son dos consultas sino **una**, por ende, si ya las tienes escritas deberás buscar la forma de **re-escribirla** en una sola.

*(Te muestro un ejemplo ya que no compartiste las sentencias SQL).*

## Estructuras y datos (similares a los que compartiste)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Consulta:

```
UPDATE
empresa
INNER JOIN
usuario
ON
usuario.id_empresa = empresa.id_empresa
SET
empresa.nombre_representante = 'ValorModificado1', usuario.campo_amodificar = 'ValorModificado2'
WHERE
empresa.id_empresa = 1
```

## Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si especificas mejor las dos consultas (la que modifica **empresa** y la que modifica **usuario**) podemos ayudarte a armar la consulta única.

Answer (score 0):

**Funciona siempre que haya valores en las dos**. Si por ejemplo tienes una relación 1a1 de las tablas: Usuarios->datos_factura podrás hacer un update de todos sus datos **si existen en ambas**. El update no funciona si sólo hay datos de usuario y aún no están dos datos de facturación para ese usuario en la otra tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo muy simple de la siguiente manera:

Suponiendo que el `usuario` es representante de la `empresa` y quieres que cuando el `usuario` actualice el `nombre` o `apellidos` también se actualice en la `empresa`.

Tienes tu `array`, que le estas pasando los valores por `$_POST`.

```
// Arreglo de datos
$datos = array('nombre'           => $this->input->post('nombre'),
               'apellido_paterno' => $this->input->post('apellidop'),
               'apellido_materno' => $this->input->post('apellidom'),
);
```

Mandas el `array` y el `id_usuario` a la función del `modelo` desde tu `controlador`:

```
if ($this->miembro->editar_miembro($datos, $id_usuario)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registro editado correctamente');
    redirect(base_url() . "index.php/perfil");
}
```

Y en tu modelo lo procesas de esta manera:

```
public function editar_miembro($datos, $id_usuario)
{
    // Seteas los datos a actualizar del usuario
    $this->db->set('u.nombre', $datos['nombre']);
    $this->db->set('u.apellido_paterno', $datos['apellido_paterno']);
    $this->db->set('u.apellido_materno', $datos['apellido_materno']);
    // Seteas los datos a actualizar de la empresa
    $this->db->set('e.nombre_representante', $datos['nombre']);
    $this->db->set('e.apellido_paterno_representante', $datos['apellido_paterno']);
    $this->db->set('e.apellido_materno_representante', $datos['apellido_materno']);
    // Condicionas
    $this->db->where('u.id_usuario', $id_usuario);
    // Condicionas que el id de empresa sea igual en usuario y empresa
    $this->db->where('u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa');
    // Actualizas
    $this->db->update('usuario as u, empresa as e');
    return true;
}
```